# Rails 3 polymorphic_path - how to change the default route_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I got a config with `Cart` and `CartItem` (`belongs_to :cart`) models.

What I want to do is to call `polymorphic_path([@cart, @cart_item])` so that it uses `cart_item_path`, instead of `cart_cart_item_path`.

I know I can change the url generated by the route to `/carts/:id/items/:id`, but that's not what I'm interested in. Also, renaming `CartItem` to `Item` is not an option. I just want to use `cart_item_path` method throughout the app.

Thanks in advance for any tip on that!

Just to make my point clear:

```
>> app.polymorphic_path([cart, cart_item])
NoMethodError: undefined method `cart_cart_item_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x007fb543e19858>
```

So, to repeat my question, what can I do in order for `polymorphic_path([cart,cart.item])` to look for `cart_item_path` and not `cart_cart_item_path`?

Answer (score 12):

After going all the way down the call stack, I came up with this:

```
module Cart    
  class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  end  

  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'cart_items'
  end

  def self.use_relative_model_naming?
    true
  end

  # use_relative_model_naming? for rails 3.1 
  def self._railtie
    true
  end
end
```

The relevant Rails code is [`ActiveModel::Naming#model_name`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L90) and [`ActiveModel::Name#initialize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L20).

Now I finally get:

```
>> cart.class
=> Cart::Cart(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
>> cart_item.class
=> Cart::Item(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
>> app.polymorphic_path([cart, cart_item])
=> "/carts/3/items/1"
>> app.send(:build_named_route_call, [cart, cart_item], :singular)
=> "cart_item_url"
```

I think the same could work for `Cart` instead of `Cart::Cart`, with `use_relative_model_naming?` on the `Cart` class level.

Comment: This answer saved my day, thanks! Note that it also affects the parameter names in forms, e.g. `Cart::Item.model_name.param_key` changes from `'cart_item'` to `'item'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the resources like this in your routes file.

```
resources :carts do
  resources :cart_items, :as => 'items'
end
```

Refer to [this section of the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names)

Comment: And that is exactly, what I'm doing. And - if you read carefully - that is the problem, because:

    `>> app.polymorphic_path([cart,cart.item])`
    `NoMethodError: undefined method `cart_cart_item_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x007fb543e19858>`

So, to repeat my question, what can I do in order for polymorphic_path([cart,cart.item]) to look for cart_tem_path and not cart_cart_item_path ?