# Explicitly non-polymorphic URL in rails url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am struggling a bit with a *clean way* to solve this.

Let's assume I have something like these models:

```
class Article
end

class FooArticle < Article
end

class BarArticle < Article
end
```

Now, I don't have a special set of routes for FooArticle and BarArticle, they both get handled by `/articles` in my app.

So I usually do article_path(@article) or new_article_path etc..

This all works fine except for the case of shared partials where I don't want to explicitly define the route:

```
form_for(@article) do |f|
  ...
end
```

The above would result in a unknown route error because it can't resolve `foo_article_path` or `bar_article_path` - yet with new records it works since I instantiate them via `@article = Article.new`.

So now the question is: Is there a method that switches path arguments so I don't have to write this code:

```
url = @article.persisted? ? article_path(@article) : articles_path
```

I explicitly don't want to use the routers polymorphic magic, but still benefit from the action auto-detection that goes on in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out:

```
Article.subclasses.each do |sub_class|
  resources sub_class.underscore.to_sym, :controller => "articles", :type => sub_class.to_s
end

underscore is ActiveSupport's method

resources :articles
```

Read this for more information

[STI, one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller)

```
class Article
  def self.subclasses
    @subclasses ||= []
  end

  def self.inherited(klass)
    @subclasses ||= []
    @subclasses << klass
  end

end
```

Comment: +1 great suggestion - unfortunately that doesn't really work in this case. (I thought of that too at first) Only problem is that my Subtypes represent user-supplied Models for Templates that are outside the scope of my Gem - so I'd like to avoid patching the routes (there are onwards of 100 article subclasses at times)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this by setting the model_name method on the child classes:
[Rails 3 polymorphic_path - how to change the default route_key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127426/rails-3-polymorphic-path-how-to-change-the-default-route-key)

but, I would be worried about possible side effects, so I would just make your own helper:

```
def form_for_article(record, options = {}, &block)  
  options.reverse_merge!({:url => record.persisted? ? article_path(record) : articles_path})
  form_for(record, options, &block)
end
```

You could generalize this if you wanted to and allow passing in the path_prefix, but that might be overkill.

Answer (score -1):

You could try looking at creating a method that uses `String.sub` or `String.sub!` (the latter modifiesi the String object in-place in memory) to change the actual value of the route temporarily, or however you need to.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve problems like form_for(@article) generating params values based on the type of `@article`. 
So `@article` = Article.new will generate params[:article] while @article = FooArticle.new will generate params[:foo_article] - making it impossible to handle it in the controller upon post